# XML Parsing Error: no element found

Tags: asp.net, xml, jquery, service

I have an ASP.Net 4.0 Web Service method that returns a well-formed XML document.  I am successfully displaying the XML in a browser locally and once deployed on the production server.

When I try to call the method via jQuery ajax I'm getting the error:

**XML Parsing Error: no element found Location: moz-nullprincipal:{6c0c99b3-0fed-454f-aa6e-e0fca93a521c} Line Number 1, Column 1:**

```
        $.ajax(
        {
            url: 'http://mywebservice.com/WebService/Service.asmx/UserData',
            type: 'GET',
            contentType: "text/html; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "xml",
            data: 'authorizedId=1234&authorizedUser=Test&authorizedCode=xyz',
            'success': function (data) {
                $('#XMLContent').html(data.responseText);

            },
            'error': function (xhr, status) {
                alert(status);
            },
            'complete': function (xhr) {
            }
        });
```

I've tried changing the contentType but same results.

However, I can make the call in C# like this and I get my well-formed XML:

```
XmlDocument document = new XmlDocument();
document.Load("http://mywebservice.com/WebService/Service.asmx/UserData?authorizedId=1234&authorizedUser=Test&authorizedCode=xyz");
ViewData["XMLData"] = document.OuterXml;
```

In my web service web.config:

```
<webServices>
  <protocols>
    <add name="HttpGet"/>
    <add name="HttpPost"/>
  </protocols>
</webServices>
```

Thanks...

Comment: I changed the web service to call to return a simple 'string' instead of XML Document:  Still getting XML Parse Error.  BTW - always getting 200 response.

Comment: Was this solved? I have something similar and I'm looking for answer.

Answer (score 2):

If the web service is not on the same domain as the page, you can not use AJAX calls to fetch data from other domains.

You can create a proxy web service in your aplication which calls your external web service, then call your own proxy from AJAX/jQuery.

http://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-ajax-and-xml-issues-no-element-found

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

Thanks bgs264...

Now in my aspx page:

```
$.ajax(
{
    url: '/Home/WebService',
    type: 'GET',
    contentType: "text/html",
    dataType: "html",
    data: 'authorizedId=1234&authorizedUser=Test&authorizedCode=xyz',
    'success': function (data) {
        alert(data);
        $('#XMLContent').html(data);
    },
    'error': function (xhr, status) {
        alert(status);
    },
    'complete': function (xhr) {
    }
});
```

In my MVC controller:

```
public ActionResult WebService(string authorizedId, string authorizedUser, string authorizedCode)
{
        XmlDocument document = new XmlDocument();
        document.Load("http://mywebservice.com/WebService/Service.asmx/UserData?authorizedId=" + authorizedId + "&authorizedUser=" + authorizedUser + "&authorizedCode=" + authorizedCode);
        ViewData["XMLData"] = document.OuterXml;
        return PartialView();
}
```